# How do I get data from API(woocommerce, Amazon mws, Shopify) in laravel and update at specific intervals

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce, laravel-5, amazon-mws

I'm quite new to laravel and thus I exactly don't know which services to use for the following thing I'm trying to do:

1. When the user inputs his credentials for Woocommerce, Amazon Mws Shopify etc, I need to get the data from their API's and store them in my database to display as datatables.
2. At a set interval of time, the data should automatically update to reflect the latest changes/additions from the respective endpoints.

An outline of the process can greatly help.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. But here's my two cents; you should look at current packages available that can help you link in to these providers, otherwise using Guzzle to help you run your API requests with the credentials required to get your information. In regards to updating the information periodically, you can just set up a scheduled task to do this on the time frame required.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get data from Amazon you can use package and write a function in controller to handle it.[this](https://packagist.org/packages/mesingh/amazon-mws-laravel) is one package that you can use.
2. Set cron job to update data periodically.